# FullCalendar continuously shows Repeating Event in-spite of start/expire date which comes from JSON, but works well with data from array

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am trying to make a simple scheduler using `FullCalendar` and when I take data from JSON it doesn't see my start/end dates, though have no problem when hardcode an array.

**Calendar.js**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        var theDate = event.start
        var endDate = event.dowend;
        var startDate = event.dowstart;

        if (theDate >= endDate) {
            return false;
            }
        if (theDate <= startDate) {
            return false;
            }
    },
    events: [{
            id: 1,
            title: "Front End",
            start: '15:00',
            end: '17:00',
            dow: [1],
            dowstart: new Date('2018-06-03'),
            dowend: new Date('2018-06-17'),
        color:'grey'
    }],
    eventSources: [{
        url: 'schedule.php',
        type: 'GET',
        },
    }],
});
```

**Schedule.php**

```
 $events = array();
foreach ($response as $var) {
    $temp['id'] = $var['id'];
    $temp['title'] = stripslashes($var['title']);
    $temp['start'] = $var['start'];
    $temp['end'] = $var['end'];
    $temp['dow'] =  array($var['dow']);
    $temp['dowstart'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var['dowstart']));
    $temp['dowend'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($var['dowend']));
    $events[] = $temp;
}

    echo json_encode($events);
```

*File outputs:*
[json-response.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2UqV.png)

Although, data of `events` array in **calendar.js** and JSON response in **schedule.php** the same, I am getting an unexpecting result in my

**index.html**

[final-result.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFxIc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `dowstart` and `dowend` are just strings, not dates. So doing a greater-than or less-than comparison on them does a simple string comparison, not a date comparison, and of course this is not reliable for your purpose.

If you convert them into momentJS objects before doing the comparison then it works correctly:

```
var endDate = moment(event.dowend);
var startDate = moment(event.dowstart);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/744/ for a working demo.

P.S. If you're wondering why the same is not necessary for the event's `start` and `end` properties, it's because these are standard properties which fullCalendar is expecting to receive for the event, and when it gets them it converts them to momentJS objects automatically (if they aren't already). Obviously with your custom properties it has no idea that you want them to be treated as dates, so you have to implement that yourself.

Comment: Thanks body! You make my life happy))